# Searching and getting results based on word frequency

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

So I have an index that has multiple documents, each document being sentences of text. For example:

Doc 1: "the cat in the hat"
Doc 2: "feed your cat lots of fish"

So I indexed them with term vectors, so I can search and see the word frequency for each document (with stopwords included):

Doc 1: "cat": 1
       "hat": 1

Doc 2: "feed": 1
       "cat":  1
       "lots": 1
       "fish": 1

So I want to be able to search this index so that if I say:

"What do I feed my cat"

This should return Doc 2, by adding up the word frequency for each document based on the query and returning the one with the highest number.

Doc 1: 1 (cat)
Doc 2: 2 (feed,cat).

Is there a way to do this in Elasticsearch? Thanks!

Comment: That would just be a match query with size set to one

Comment: If you have multiple fields then use multimatch query. Also see this about scoring works or doesn't https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/relevance-is-broken.html